# Different WordData results between notebook and command line

Tags: command-line, scripting, curated-data

When I run

```
p = WordData["classy", "PhoneticForm"];
Print[p];
Print[StringLength[p] ];
```

in a notebook, the result is

```
klˈæsi
6
```

Note that the result is 6 Unicode characters. However, when I run it at the command line, i.e., in a text file that begins with

```
#!/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathematicaScript -script
```

the result is

```
kl'asee
7
```

You can see that the command-line result is ASCII: the IPA symbol `æ` was converted to `a` and the IPA `i` to `ee`.

This breaks my program, which finds similar-sounding words based on the first character after the accent, eg, "foxy" & "cocky":

```
WordData["foxy",  "PhoneticForm"]
WordData["cocky", "PhoneticForm"]
```

returns

```
fˈɒksi
kˈɒki
```

which sound the same because in both cases the character `ɒ` follows the accent. But at the command line, two **dissimilar** words --- "foxy" and "astute" --- are incorrectly considered to be similar, because

```
WordData["foxy",   "PhoneticForm"]
WordData["astute", "PhoneticForm"]
```

returns

```
uhst'oot
f'oksee
```

which both have `o` following the accent (despite the top `o` is actually `oo`).

It's pretty scary that calling MMA from the command line produces different output than in the front-end. Am I missing something?

**How can I get a MathematicaScript script to produce the same (Unicode) output as the Front End?**

Comment: Seems like it is a result of different realizations of the kernel function. The same result is returned even if you run X-Win on Linux and evaluate in a notebook. It seems like you need to assume this result as a default and parse this syntax in your function accounting for _oo_ vs. _o_ difference. You can then always get the same result even in a Windows notebook by calling `CloudEvaluate@WordData["classy", "PhoneticForm"]`

Comment: @Stitch: Yes, I can confirm that the "oo" ASCII form is returned even in the graphical Front End when MMA is running on Linux. Thanks for the suggestion to use CloudEvaluate (which also returns the ASCII form).